# Конфигурация nginx запущенного в docker-compoze

Tags: nginx, docker, docker-compose

Мне для целей разработки, нужно поднять в докере ряд приложений написанных на Asp.net core WebApi.

Compose:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:stable-alpine  
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:81:80"
      - "127.0.0.1:443:443"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
      - ./nginx/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    restart: unless-stopped
    container_name: nginx
    extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
```

Конфигурация самого проксирования, находится в файле
по пути **./nginx/conf.d/test.conf**, который заполнен следующим образом:

```
    server {
    listen       127.0.0.1:80;
    
    location /foo/ {
 
        proxy_pass http://host.docker.internal:1002;
    }

}
```

т.е. я ожидаю, при переходе на **http://localhost:81/foo/swagger** увидеть сваггер своего сервиса (который расположен по адресу http://localhost:1002/swagger). однако, вместо этого, в логах nginx я вижу сообщения об ошибке:

```
[error] 29#29: *1 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/foo/swagger" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 192.168.240.1, server: _, request: "GET /foo/swagger HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"
```

**Однако если не использовать префикс /foo, а использовать перенаправление только на корень "/", то все работает кооректно и я виду сваггер. Подскажите что не так с настройками?**

UPD:

Пробовал пробросить proxy_pass через внутреннюю сеть докера (в первом композ файле создать сеть и присвоить имя к запущенному а в nginx подключиться к сети и проксировать внутреннюю сеть через nginx.) В итоге результат тот же, если не применять префикс /foo а настроить на корень, то все работает. Прошу советов / идей.

Comment: Скорее всего, вам нужно добавить перенаправление в конфиге прокси. `rewrite    /foo/(.*) /$1 break;` Можете посмотреть примеры тут https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32542282/how-do-i-rewrite-urls-in-a-proxy-response-in-nginx

Comment: @AlexanderKiselev помогло, благодарю.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это широко известная в узких кругах особенность конфигурации `proxy_pass`

Вы написали в конфигурации

```
proxy_pass http://host.docker.internal:1002;
```

В конце URL **нет** `/`, поэтому в `proxy_pass` переадресация просходит по тому же пути, который использовался в исходном запросе. Вы запросили `/foo/swagger`? Получите обращение к `http://host.docker.internal:1002/foo/swagger`

Если вам не нужен префикс `/foo/`, то вам нужно написать

```
proxy_pass http://host.docker.internal:1002/;
```

Обратите внимание на **косую черту в конце**! общее правило звучит так: префикс из правила заменяется на путь, указанный в URL. То есть вашем случае запрос к `/foo/swagger` будет обслужен как `/swagger`: `nginx` заменит префикс `/foo/` из правила на `/` из URL.

Comment: Благодарю. Получилось.